# Making Elastic Beanstalk domain HTTPS, getting error on deployment - undefined resource AWSEBLoadBalancer

Tags: https, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

So I have a domain http://leafapi.co.uk/ linked to my elastic beanstalk environment successfully and I'm trying to set it up with HTTPS. I've set up a load balancer listener on 443 in my elastic beanstalk configuration using an SSL certificate.

I think the last thing I need to do is configure a security group from my project file with a config file that looks like this:

```
Resources:
  sslSecurityGroupIngress:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress
    Properties:
      GroupId: {"Fn::GetAtt" : ["AWSEBSecurityGroup", "GroupId"]}
      IpProtocol: tcp
      ToPort: 443
      FromPort: 443
      SourceSecurityGroupName: {"Fn::GetAtt" : ["AWSEBLoadBalancer" , "SourceSecurityGroup.GroupName"]}
```

However when I try to deploy I get the following error:

`Service:AmazonCloudFormation, Message:Template error: instance of Fn::GetAtt references undefined resource AWSEBLoadBalancer`

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I got this when trying to update from a Classic Load Balancer to an Application Load Balancer - in this case AWSEBLoadBalancer was no longer defined but AWSEBV2LoadBalancer now was.

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-format-resources-eb.html

Answer (score 0):

The problem was actually that I prepended my SSL certificate domain name with 'www.'. After getting the right SSL certificate it worked without the config above.